# Framework used to develop the new windows azure management portal?

Tags: asp.net, frameworks, azure, microsoft-metro

Does anyone know what framework microsoft used to develop the metro like web management portal on windows azure. If so. Is it available to developers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KnockOut Js

Require Js

TypeScript

Less

ASP.NET

D3 Js
Web sockets

Some links for more information
[Steve Sanderson - Architecting large Single Page Applications with Knockout.js](https://vimeo.com/97519516)

[Under the hood of the new Azure Portal](https://jbeckwith.com/2014/09/20/how-the-azure-portal-works/)

[From the ground up: Building the Microsoft Azure Preview Portal](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/From-the-ground-up-on-the-Microsoft-Azure-Preview-Portal/player?h=540&w=960)

[Framework used to develop the new windows azure management portal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118022/framework-used-to-develop-the-new-windows-azure-management-portal)

Credit [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-tools-Microsoft-used-to-build-the-new-Azure-portal)

Answer (score 7):

I [posed the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713118/library-for-developing-azure-web-interface-style-web-sites) and got a lot of hate for it. The winning answer is the [Metro UI Pack](http://metroui.org.ua/). It does a lot of what they do in Azure, but you'd have to implement the rest yourself.

Comment: I was told by a friend works for DPE at MS that the classic portal was built on a custom framework that wouldn't go out. I was pointed to METRO UI PACK as the best way to emulate that look  and feel. Now the new portal that is in beta is some sort of SPA framework but is obscured regarding its basis or origin.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS is probably custom, but the portal uses a few open source libraries for the javascript part:

- jquery-1.7.1
- jquery-ui
- jsObservable
- JsRender
- JsViews
- jquery.event.drag

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this codepen: https://codepen.io/utillity/project/editor/ArjgLa

```
It's basically a cascade of flexboxes.
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft probably did not use this framework, but you might try [jq-metro](http://www.jqmetro.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for angular component library for Metro,  it is [here](https://morrisjdev.github.io/ng-metro4/#/)