# Library for Developing Azure Web Interface Style Web Sites

Tags: javascript, html, css, azure

The management at my company really likes the web interface for managing your Windows Azure sites - and I don't blame them. It's a unique and easy to use product. I was wondering if anyone out there knew of an API that allowed you to mimic the look and feel of the Azure web interface. I know Microsoft has been all about the Open Source lately, perhaps they have even released the source code for the Azure web interface? I've Googled the hell out of it and can't find anything.

To be clear, I'm referring to a CSS/HTML/Javascript library that mimics their page layout - especially the way the left navigation collapses into icons, optionally showing a sub-menu of the selected item, and the way they have the contextually sensitive bar across the bottom of the page.

**EDIT**: ModernDesigner pointed out the [Metro UI CSS](http://www.metroui.org.ua/) kit, which is a solid start, but what about the nice collapsible side-bar that Azure has?

Comment: I think you're wanting the Metro UI pack: http://www.metroui.org.ua/

Comment: Hey down-voters. Can you at least leave me a comment so that I can improve my question to make it more clear?

Comment: Well, (I didn't downvote), but they're doing it because this is a site about programming. Not general discussion/suggestions. It needs to be Q & A format. (What's wrong with this? A: This) not (What would you suggest? A: This)

Comment: i have a feeling some people are downvoting microsoft azure, not your question

Comment: @ModernDesigner, Hmm... You have a point. I guess they didn't read the tool-tip for down-voting. It's if the question doesn't show research effort or is unclear or not useful.

Comment: Yep. That's why I upvoted and kept you at 0 for a split second. And @statichippo +1 Lol. Probably.

Comment: Honest feedback on your downvotes: The title sounds like a command ("Do this for me!") which will usually attract a negative response, and "Does X exist?" questions are generally off topic, often they can be answered with "No".

Comment: Thanks @WesleyMurch. I changed the title. It's ironic when you receive down-votes, but other people Favorite your Q.

Comment: @Grinn, well, I already pretty much said the same thing in the comments, so I figured it redundant. But I put it back.

Comment: Your question doesn't fit the purpose of Stack Overflow. @Wesley Murch is just right and this has nothing to to with "Microsoft hating" or what so ever.

Comment: @kleinfreund I'm sure, but he was joking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118022/framework-used-to-develop-the-new-windows-azure-management-portal

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're wanting the [Metro UI Pack](http://metroui.org.ua/). The user interface concept (was) called Metro. Everybody knows it as metro, but then it was called the Modern UI, now it's just called the Windows UI. But if you search for Metro UI, you'll get a lot of stuff. Hope this helps.

**Edit**: In response to your edit, collapsible sidebars can be used by creating charms (metro ui), then using jQuery toggle/animation methods. I don't know that there's a premade API that will allow you to do this as it is waaay to broad, each user will have different ideas and want different customization options, so there's no way really to adhere to that specific need. However, I did find [this](http://www.jqmetro.com/Pages/), and on the bottom gray bar, if you click the ellipses in the right corner, it has something similar to what you may want.